# Configure Availability Group in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016, clustering, aws

Can you tell me how you add the second node as the replica to the AG?

I am using this feature on AWS instances, I have followed all the steps as shown in different videos, but when I try to add the secondary node as the replica, it does not work. It only takes one name and that is the SQL Cluster name that I had given during SQL Cluster fail over installation on the primary node.

Can you guide me on this? Also, I am able to login both the SQL instances only with SQL Cluster name as well as Server name.

Comment: Can you list the steps you've completed, in order? That way, we can see if anything was left out?

Comment: Please include all steps you've taken and details of the error messages you're encountering